# Prompting and waiting for the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scripting

I've searched all over the internet but couldn't solve the problem.

I am coding a game. Before the game starts, I prompt the user for difficulty, and user have to select a difficulty to start the game by clicking one of the buttons.

```
function GameManager(){
    this.current = 0;
    this.difficulty = 0;
    this.toolbox = new Toolbox();
    this.promptDifficulty();            // Here it should wait for user input
    this.grid = new Grid(this.difficulty);
    this.start();
}

GameManager.prototype.promptDifficulty = function() {
    $("#difficulty").show();
    this.toolbox.center();
    var selected = false;
    $('.selection').click(function(){
        var $diff = $(this).attr('id');
        if($diff === 'easy')
            this.difficulty = 8;
        else if($diff === 'medium')
            this.difficulty = 9;
        else if($diff === 'hard')
            this.difficulty = 10;
        $('#difficulty').hide();
    });
};
```

However, it creates the Grid before the user selects the difficulty, and this messes up whole design. How can I make it wait until user clicks one of the difficulty settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the difficulty prompt is an async method, when you call the `promptDifficulty()` method, it shows the difficulty selector, but the rest of the script execution will continue before the user selects an item. So you need to use a callback to continue, which will be called once the user selects an item.

```
function GameManager() {
    this.current = 0;
    this.difficulty = 0;
    this.toolbox = new Toolbox();
    this.promptDifficulty($.proxy(function (difficulty) {
        this.grid = new Grid(this.difficulty);
        this.start();
    }, this));
}

GameManager.prototype.promptDifficulty = function (callback) {
    $("#difficulty").show();
    this.toolbox.center();
    var selected = false;
    $('.selection').click($.proxy(function (e) {
        var $diff = e.currentTarget.id;

        if ($diff === 'easy') this.difficulty = 8;
        else if ($diff === 'medium') this.difficulty = 9;
        else if ($diff === 'hard') this.difficulty = 10;
        $('#difficulty').hide();

        callback(this.difficulty);
    }, this));
};
```

Also Note the use of [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), because in the click handler `this` by default refers to the  clicked element, so when you set `this.difficulty` it is not setting to the `GameManager` instance, you can solve by passing a custom execution context for the callback method.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4jsMb/)

Comment: Can you explain the code so I can fix it? Because I've never got the concept of callbacks, and the code doesn't seem to work properly again. this.difficulty seems to assigned to a div element instead of an integer(8,9 or 10).

Comment: $.proxy() doesn't seem to help it. Still assigns the wrong value to the difficulty.

Comment: @BurakÖzmen missed to pass a `this` to `$.proxy()` - see the update